# "IO::Socket::SSL 1.94+ required for TLS support" Error when running Mojolicious App on Heroku

Tags: perl, ssl, heroku, mojolicious

I have followed the instructions from here [Tempire's Mojolicious Deploy App Heroku](https://github.com/tempire/mojolicious-command-deploy-heroku). Everything works fine and I have verified that all prerequisites in Makefile.PL are there. Running this command from my terminal gives me IO::Socket::SSL is up to date (2.027).
Net::SSLeay is up to date (1.74).

```
heroku run --app sheltered-island-80963 -- /app/vendor/perl/bin/perl /app/vendor/perl/bin/cpan IO::Socket::SSL Net::SSLeay
```

However, I have a controller that performs some http requests before rendering and when I try to use UserAgent, it gives me the error that IO::Socket::SSL 1.94 is required. The app runs fine locally but fails on heroku.

I have tried to disable TLS by setting MOJO_NO_TLS=1 but still the error persists. Anyone know of a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that you have two Perls. One has the modules and the other runs the application. I couldn't be sure without being able to dig in more. I don't especially like installing modules via the heroku command though, they should be in the make file.

Perhaps make a route that dumps %INC into the browser (temporarily) after attempting the request that fails.

Comment: You were right. After some digging around, I found out that there were actually more than two Perl's installed.